# get class(Something something) into final

Tags: java, class

I don't quite know how to explain this but I have `Triangle.class` and `Main.class` and I am trying to get an edge from the public Triangle:

Triangle:

```
public class Triangle {

    public Triangle(Edge ab, Edge bc, Edge ca) {

    }
    private int perimeter;
    private boolean isATriangle;
    private Edge edge1;
    private Edge edge2;
    private Edge edge3;

    public boolean isTriangle(Triangle triangle){

        if(edge1.getLength() + edge2.getLength() > edge3.getLength() &&
           edge2.getLength()+edge3.getLength() > edge1.getLength() &&
           edge3.getLength()+edge1.getLength() > edge2.getLength()){
            return isATriangle = true;
        }
        else{
            return isATriangle = false;
            }
    }

    public int setPerimeter(int perimeter1) {
        return this.perimeter = perimeter1;     
    }

    public int getPerimeter() {
        return Integer.valueOf(perimeter);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Let me make myself clear because I know I wasnt clear.
I want to create a "public boolean isTriangle(Triangle triangle){" and to get edge1 edge2 and edge3 that makes Triangle triangle. how can I do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. This snippet: `final Edge edgeA = ab;` doesn't make sense on its own because `ab` is a parameter for the constructor. You can't use `ab` outside the constructor. What do you mean?

Comment: I realise that I wasnt clear. Look at the edit - I want to get the 3 edges that create the triangle. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your Edge fields are marked as private like this:

```
private Edge edge1;
```

You can make them public or define `get` functions on the Triangle class